# Using GridSearchCV with TimeSeriesSplit

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, grid-search

I have some code that would use `TimeSeriesSplit` to split my data. For each split, I would use `ParametersGrid` and loop through each parameter combination, record the best set of params and use it to predict my `X_test`. You can see the code for this part at the bottom of the post

I understand that `GridSearchCV` will do a lot of that work for me. I'm wondering if I use the following code, where does my data get split into 
`X_train`, `X_test`, `y_train` and `y_test`? Will using the `GridSearchCV` with the `TimeSeriesSplit` handle this behind the scenes and if so will this code accomplish the same thing as my original code at the bottom of this post? Also, i've now tried the `GridSearchCV` method and it's been almost 30 min without finishing - do i have the right syntax?

```
X = data.iloc[:, 0:8]
y = data.iloc[:, 8:9]

parameters = [
    {'kernel': ['rbf'],
     'gamma': [.01],
     'C': [1, 10, 100]}]

gsc = GridSearchCV(SVR(), param_grid=parameters, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error', 
                   cv=TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=2))
gsc.fit(X,y)
means = gsc.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
for mean in means:
    print(mean)
print('end')
```

Original Code Below:

```
# Create the time series split generator
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=3)

for train_index, test_index in tqdm(tscv.split(X)):

X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]

# scale the data set
scaler_X = StandardScaler()
scaler_y = StandardScaler()
scaler_X.fit(X_train)
scaler_y.fit(y_train)
X_train, X_test = scaler_X.transform(X_train), scaler_X.transform(X_test)
y_train, y_test = scaler_y.transform(y_train), scaler_y.transform(y_test)


# optimization area - set params
parameters = [
    {'kernel': ['rbf'],
     'gamma': [.01],
     'C': [ 1,10,100,500,1000]}]


regressor = SVR()
# loop through each of the parameters and find the best set
for e, g in enumerate(ParameterGrid(parameters)):
    regressor.set_params(**g)
    regressor.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())
    score = metrics.mean_absolute_error(regressor.predict(X_train), y_train.ravel())
    if e == 0:
        best_score = score
        best_params = g
    elif score < best_score:
        best_score = score
        best_params = g


# refit the model with the best set of params

regressor.set_params(**best_params)
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the code slightly.

```
gsc = GridSearchCV(SVR(), param_grid=parameters, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error', 
                   cv=TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=2).split(X))
```

And, you can consider adding `verbose` parameter to look at running output.

Comment: ahh I see - but where does y get split? I had to specify that when I was doing it manually

Comment: Also - is there a reason the GridSearchCV method would take longer to run than my "original code" method?

Comment: `split()` method generates indices to split data into training and test set. Those indices will then be applied to `X` and `y` to actually split the data.

Comment: From a quick glance, I could not find any obvious reason why `GridSearchCV` will perform poorly than the other code. Couple of suggestions - set `n_jobs=-1` so that is uses all processors, and set `kernel` and `gamma` when instantiating `SVR()`, unless you plan to test with more values for these parameters (right now there in only one in the grid).

Comment: Yea i was just deleting parameters to test for gamma to try and get it to finish running. I'll try the n_jobs setting. So the two code snippets I have are basically doing the same thing, right?

Comment: I have never looked at the implementation of GridSearchCV, but logically yes, both does the same. Just a suggestion - (1) in your code I would probably remove the `if e == 0:` block, instead initialize `best_score` and `score` to 0 before the `for loop`. And (2)  the `score < best_score` logic is wrong, it should be the other way round. You want to set `best_score` to `score` only if latest score beats the so far best_score.

Comment: the problem if i do some of those suggestions is that smallest mean absolute error to be chosen as the best so thats why if its less than the best score it'll go in. Also, if i initialize to 0 then when it comes to metrics like r^2 i'd have to go in and change the initialization number - this way i can just change the sign if higher number is better and vice versa. let me know if that logic is flawed

Comment: Ah right, I forgot that you are calculating the MSE in score, so lower the better. Please ignore my last comment then. Also, just to clarify, those suggestions had nothing to do with performance. Is it working now after making the change suggested in original answer? If yes, please consider "accepting" the answer :)

Comment: Adding verbose let me see that it was running and seemed to finish all 4 jobs but it doesn't go on to calculate any further code - prob why I thought it was taking so long to run. Can't figure out whats wrong

Comment: You mean the `mean` or `end` is not printing?